# How to verify if the system has periodic solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, periodic-functions

I have the following differential system
\begin{cases}
  x'(t) =y(t)+[1-x^2(t)-y^2(t)]x(t) \\
  y'(t)=-x(t)+[1-2x^2(t)-y^2(t)]y(t) \\
\end{cases}
How can I see if there exist some periodic solutions?

I only know Bendixson's theorem that gives me a sufficient condition for the non-existence of periodic solution..

Comment: The Poincare-Bendixon theorem allows you to determine the existence of a closed orbit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a circular trapping region, which works in many exercise examples, the first to consider is the radius dynamic
$$
rr'=xx'+yy'=r^2(1-r^2)-x^2y^2.
$$
Then use that $0\le x^2y^2\le \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}4$ to find the inequalities
$$
r\left(1-\frac54r^2\right)\le r'\le r^2(1-r^2)
$$
so that $r'$ is guaranteed to be non-negative for $0\le r\le\frac2{\sqrt5}$ and non-positive for $r\ge 1$.

It remains to check that there are no stationary points of the system inside the annulus between these regions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer to your question, as it does not constitute a proof. However, it is inconvenient to post it as a comment.

Running numerical simulations we can see that there is a single periodic solution, which is the $\omega$-limit of every other orbit (except for the constant orbit $x=y=0$).

[image]